# Socket.io: disconnect, reconnect events etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to get a handle on the various connection/disconnection events and how to use these to make sure that my application will always terminate gracefully.

I understand that socket.io will automatically attempt to reconnect a specified number of times. It is my understanding that as the connection goes down and subsequently reconnects there will be a disconnection event fired server side. I do not care about the connection temporarily going down **so long as it comes back up at some point**.

However if there is a more permanent disconnect, I do care about this and would need to update data such as connected users. I understand that on the client side you can get a reconnect_failed error object but I do not believe you can listen for this on the server. Is there any way to get notification on the server side that the connection is down and reconnection has failed? If so how does socket.io implement this?

I could issue a timeout upon a disconnection event server side that removes users if there is no reconnection. I could also have the server ping all connected clients at certain intervals. Are these kinds of solutions the only way to **completely** deal with all kinds of possible disconnections?